# How can I access selected cell from collectionView of items? // items stored firebase

Tags: ios, swift

I connect my swift app with firebase and now I'm trying to get item key of selected item from the collection view to store selected item to the cart.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage
class ViewController6: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var itemCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var customItemFlowLayout: CustomItemFlowLayout!
    var items = [itemsL]()
    //var ind = 0


    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        nextButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("items")
        loadDB()

        customItemFlowLayout = CustomItemFlowLayout()
        itemCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = customItemFlowLayout
        //itemCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white

    }

      func loadDB(){
        dbRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newItems = [itemsL]()


            for itemsLSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                // condition for filtring items
                if itemsL.init(snapshot:  itemsLSnapshot as! DataSnapshot).key >= "2"{


                    // bring item
                    // #######
                let itemsLObject = itemsL(snapshot: itemsLSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
                newItems.append(itemsLObject)
                    // #######
                }

            }
            self.items = newItems
            self.itemCollectionView.reloadData()
        })
      }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return items.count
      }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt IndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
          let cell = itemCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: IndexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell

          let item = items[IndexPath.row]

            cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: item.url),placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "image22"))
            cell.itemName.text = item.itemName
            cell.price.text = item.price

            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

          return cell
      }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 3
        cell?.isSelected = true
        }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell?.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

[image: items in firebase]

Comment: can you clearify your question more ?  do you mean you want to access to your cell item on click row ?

Comment: let me explain, I want user select item and then move to another page then select one more item and so on, after that I want to show items that user select (like cart).

Comment: so you want to change the view when user select item from list right

Comment: no, there is a button for moving to next page, I just color the cell border with different color if user click on the item.

Comment: ah so you need to save that selected things somewhere right to get it in the other view ?

Comment: yeah that what I need

Comment: you can store your selected data into array and then when navigating to next view you can send this array of data to next view as well

Comment: yeah that's good but my problem it's that I don't know how to get item information or item key, I just found the indexPath of the selected item.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: have you tried items[indexPath.row] to get your selected data object ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code selects and deselects the cell but the state is not persistent.

The most reliably way to make the selection persistent is to add a property in the model

```
struct ItemsL { // please name structs with starting capital letter

    var isSelected = false
    // other properties
}
```

In `cellForItemAt` select the cell depending on this property

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = itemCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: IndexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell

    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: item.url),placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "image22"))
    cell.itemName.text = item.itemName
    cell.price.text = item.price
    if item.isSelected {
       cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
       cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
       cell.isSelected = true
    } else {
       cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
       cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
       cell.isSelected = false
    }
    return cell
}
```

In `didSelectItemAt` toggle `isSelected` and reload the item, `didDeselectItemAt` is not needed.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    items[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ....
}
```

To get the selected items filter the array

```
let selectedItems = items.filter{ $0.isSelected }
```

Comment: I got this error .. (Value of type 'itemsL' has no member 'isSelected') after I put didSelectItemAt

Comment: Did you add the property in the struct/class (first code snippet)?

Comment: its working, but now the customer can select more than one item, I just want them be able to select one item like when they press on one item the other one become unselect.

Comment: Of course it supports multi-selection, that's what your question implies. Add a property `selectedRow : IndexPath` in the controller, set `isSelected` of the item at `selectedRow` to `false` and of the item at `indexPath` to `true` in `didSelectAt`. Then reload both rows.

Comment: I'm sorry I mean one selection from each viewController, I have 6 viewController so I want user select 6 items one from each viewController then I get the selected items and put them in table view like cart. so the process is like user join to first viewController and select one item then press next button to another viewController and so on.